# swift When I click on didselectRow I want to see the json data on the detail page image , title and year?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

When I click on it, I want to show the picture title and year part in the cell section in the tableview, how can I do this? When we click on the row go detail page and big picture, title and year  I want to show the big title and year. How can I populate the DetailViewController page?

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var field: UITextField!

    var movies = [Movie]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        table.register(MovieTableViewCell.nib(), forCellReuseIdentifier: MovieTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.delegate = self
        table.dataSource = self
        field.delegate = self
    }

    // Field
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        searchMovies()
        return true
    }

    func searchMovies() {
        field.resignFirstResponder()

        guard let text = field.text, !text.isEmpty else {
            return
        }

        let query = text.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

        movies.removeAll()

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=3aea79ac&s=\(query)&type=movie")!,
                                   completionHandler: { data, response, error in

                                    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                                        return
                                    }

                                    // Convert
                                    var result: MovieResult?
                                    do {
                                        result = try JSONDecoder().decode(MovieResult.self, from: data)
                                    }
                                    catch {
                                        print("error")
                                    }

                                    guard let finalResult = result else {
                                        return
                                    }

                                    // Update our movies array
                                    let newMovies = finalResult.Search
                                    self.movies.append(contentsOf: newMovies)

                                    // Refresh our table
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.table.reloadData()
                                    }

        }).resume()

    }

    // Table

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return movies.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MovieTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MovieTableViewCell
        cell.configure(with: movies[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        // Show movie details
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "detailViewController") as? detailViewController{
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }



struct MovieResult: Codable {
    let Search: [Movie]
}

struct Movie: Codable {
    let Title: String
    let Year: String
    let imdbID: String
    let _Type: String
    let Poster: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case Title, Year, imdbID, _Type = "Type", Poster
    }
}
```

MovieTableViewCell

```
class MovieTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var movieTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var movieYearLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var moviePosterImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    static let identifier = "MovieTableViewCell"

    static func nib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: "MovieTableViewCell",
                     bundle: nil)
    }

    func configure(with model: Movie) {
        self.movieTitleLabel.text = model.Title
        self.movieYearLabel.text = model.Year
        let url = model.Poster
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(string: url)!) {
            self.moviePosterImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }
    
}
```

DetailViewController

```
import UIKit

class detailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yearLbl: UILabel!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        }
}
```

Comment: In `detailViewController`, add a `var movie: Movie`, and before `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`, do `vc.movie =  movies[indexPath.row]`. Then, in the `viewDidLoad()` of `detailViewController`, do `titleLabel.text = movie.Title`, and follow the same logic for all the other info: image, year, etc.

Comment: Now, unrelated, BUT, there are a big thing that should be avoided: Avoid using ` Data(contentsOf:)`, especially to load an image.  In your case, it's called in main thread, it's blocking the current thread, so the UI, and everything becomes laggy. Now, variable should start with a lowercase, and class/struct name with an uppercase.

Comment: i'm new to swift and i don't know how to do some things :/

Comment: thank you, I solved the problem. How can I add the json result not found warning? warning message for users to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data there when you create your UIViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Show movie details
    if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "detailViewController") as? detailViewController{
        vc.item = movies[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

But you need to pass data first, and when you controller initialized (loaded) you can assign value to loaded views

```
class detailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var yearLbl: UILabel!
    
    var item: Movie? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if (let movie = item) {
            titleLbl.text = item.title
            yearLbl.tex = item.Year
                // also image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you answer i figured very happy now

Comment: How can I add the json result not found warning? warning message for users to see

Comment: based on how you want to display it. The simplest way will be to display `UIAlertViewController`, for example: 

   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Something went wrong",        preferredStyle: .alert)
   alert.addAction(.init(title: "Close", style: .default, nil))
   self.navigationController.present(alert)

Comment: As you said, I delete the print("error") in the 'catch' section of the UIViewController page and place it as you say, but when I enter an incorrect search, it causes the application to crash. this is crash = Thread 3: "Call must be made on main thread"

Comment: It needs to call inside `DispatchQueue.main.async { // here }` same you use to reload the table